# LibGDX How to disable a camera zoom at android devices?

Tags: android, libgdx

I mean increase of a picture with fingers. In my program this is not provided, so I need to disable this feature.

Comment: What u have tried so far?

Comment: Is the gesture not recognized, or the library not responding?

Comment: Nothing like that should happen by default. If this can be done in any app, it's probably a modified Android version and you might be able to disable that via the android.manifest configuration. However I have never heard of anything like that and usually you need to implement that yourself to make finger gestures work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the ability to zoom in like this

```
// First create a camera and a CameraInputController
PerspectiveCamera cam = new PerspectiveCamera();
CameraInputController camController = new CameraInputController(cam);

// And disable the ability to zoom in or out by pinching
camController.pinchZoomFactor = 0;
```